# Looping through a large number of database rows in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm using Yii2 and my database server is MySQL. I need to scan every row of a whole db table searching for occurrences of some text.

This is what I want but because of the large number of records, I'm not sure if I do it like this the server won't run out of memory or the MySQL server wont go away:

```
$rows = Posts::find()->select('content')->all();
foreach($rows as $post) {
    // do some regex on $post['content']. no need to save it back to the table.
}
```

It's a live server with a large database. I must do it on the fly, can't take down the server for back up and restore!

Would this work? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: go for background processing. In yii2 see the docs for console application http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html

Comment: Instead of looping through the records (which could lead to memory problems), you could simply use REGEXP in your query...

Comment: Since I need to extract the matched patterns from the field and I'm not clear on how to do it in MySQL, I'd rather go with the Yii "batch" or "each" method. It seems to do the trick. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why not use Query Builder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following two subsections of [Accessing Data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#accessing-data) in Yii2 Guide have talked about your issue:

- Retrieving Data in Arrays

  ```
  use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
  $contents = ArrayHelper::getColumn(
    Post::find()->asArray()->all(),
    'content'
  );
  foreach ($contents as $content) {

  }
  ```
- Retrieving Data in Batches

  ```
  // fetch 10 rows at a time
  foreach(Posts::find()->select('content')->each(10) as $post) {
      // ...
  }
  ```

Both methods could reduce memory cost.